# jTinder Save to Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I hope it's ok to ask this here. I have searched everywhere, but can't find a solution.
I've found a nice js library called jTinder at https://github.com/do-web/jTinder

Now I am trying to save likes or dislikes in a mysql database and php. But soon I will give up! I've tried a lots of different code, but nothing really happens.
Mostly I crasch the script from working at all.

Can someone help me?

```
$("#tinderslide").jTinder({
// dislike callback
onDislike: function (item) {
    // set the status text
    $('#status').html('Dislike image ' + (item.index()+1));


    },


// like callback
onLike: function (item) {
    // set the status text
    $('#status').html('Like image ' + (item.index()+1));
},
animationRevertSpeed: 200,
animationSpeed: 400,
threshold: 1,
likeSelector: '.like',
dislikeSelector: '.dislike'
});
```

getdata.php looks like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "vacation");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$liked = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['like']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO destinations (like) VALUES ('$liked')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}


mysqli_close($link);
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({                                
  url: 'getdata.php',              


  dataType: 'json',                   
  success: function(data)         
  {
    var id = data[0];             
    var name = data[1];

    var count = data[3];


    $('#output').html('like('+id+')');

  }
```

Comment: use ajax to save it to your database

Comment: Thats what I've been trying to do. But everytime I eighter freeze the code or nothing happens. I dont know where to put the ajax call. I have a getdata.php

Comment: put it to your question for better understand and also provide the code with the ajax so that we can tell where you are going wrong

Comment: I've edited my question. Its the ajax call I tried to insert in onDislike function. And if it would work, I copy it to onLike function.

Answer (score 0):

There a are many problem in this code so

In your html file where is data coming from in ajax while you are not returning anything in you php code. So your code sholud be somthing like the for test

```
$("#tinderslide").jTinder({
// dislike callback
        onDislike: function (item) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'getdata.php',
                data: 'DATA_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log()

                    //$('#output').html('like(' + id + ')');

                }
            });
                // set the status text
            $('#status').html('Dislike image ' + (item.index()+1));


        },

// like callback
        onLike: function (item) {
            // set the status text
            $('#status').html('Like image ' + (item.index()+1));
        },
        animationRevertSpeed: 200,
        animationSpeed: 400,
        threshold: 1,
        likeSelector: '.like',
        dislikeSelector: '.dislike'
    });
```

And in php code
You are inserting like into it how do you get a post data in the php file if you are not sending it from the ajax so put data to it.

Comment: Its not the complete solution but its where you are worng If you give the code in right way so its more easy to understand

Comment: Acctually I was trying to set up a fun way for my family to vote for next destination we are going to on holiday.
I think this has became way out of my leage. :-/
I'm only familiar with simple php and mysql.
I'm sorry for mess up!